# Declining balances issue

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, amortization

I am showing the declining balance of a loan per year and the interest paid per year. The first and second year are always messed up, causing the rest of the years to not be correct. Also, how do I print a column with designated space for each entry, besides using spaces to separate them like I did?

My code:

```
int year;
periods = loanDurationYears*12;
double annualBalance = 0;
double annualInterest = 0;   
int month = loanDurationYears-(loanDurationYears-1);

            balance = loanAmount;
            double interestForMonth = balance*((interestRate*.01)/12);
            double principalForMonth = monthlyPayment - interestForMonth;
            balance = balance - principalForMonth;
            System.out.println("Annual balances");
            System.out.printf("%s   %s   %s \n","Year","Interest","Balance");

            for(int j=0;j<periods;j++)
            {
                month++;
                year = month/12;

                interestForMonth = balance*((interestRate*.01)/12);
                principalForMonth = monthlyPayment - interestForMonth;
                balance = balance - principalForMonth;
                annualBalance = annualBalance + balance;
                annualInterest = annualInterest + interestForMonth;

                if(month%12 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.printf("%d      %.2f    %.2f \n",year,annualInterest,annualBalance);
                    annualBalance = 0;
                    annualInterest = 0;
                }


            }
```

My output:

```
Year   Interest   Balance 
1      4852.43    859718.74 
2      5080.12    899718.26 
3      4842.34    857208.50 
4      4588.01    811738.89 
5      4315.96    763103.31 
6      4024.98    711081.35 
7      3713.73    655437.20 
8      3380.81    595918.66 
9      3024.71    532255.97 
10      2643.82    464160.58 
11      2236.40    391323.84 
12      1800.62    313415.64 
13      1334.49    230082.85 
14      835.91    140947.76 
15      302.62    45606.39
```

How the output should look: (besides the columns not being aligned)

```
Year    Interest    Loan Balance
1   5965.23          86408.21   
    2   5715.14      82566.33    
    3   5447.64      78456.94    
    4   5161.51      74061.43    
    5   4855.46      69359.87    
6   4528.10      64330.94    
    7   4177.95      58951.87    
    8   3803.41      53198.26    
    9   3402.80      47044.03    
    10  2974.29      40461.31    
    11  2515.95  33420.24    
    12      2025.70  25888.91    
    13  1501.31  17833.19    
    14  940.40   9216.58    
    15      340.45   -0.00
```

Comment: For spacing, you could start by trying `\t` (tab) instead of multiple spaces. To get it to reliably line up you'll have to do more complicated calculations though since each number's length will potentially be different.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an incorrect starting amount because you adjust the balance before the for-loop. It looks like your for-loop expects to start with the full balance, but it's already been reduced.  You should also either move the increment of `month` to the end of the loop, or start it at zero instead of 1.

This line will always initialize `month` to 1. Why bother with the math?

```
int month = loanDurationYears-(loanDurationYears-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this or anything but it should work. I'm sure it's not the best fix but something simple like this should work fine.

It simply checks the size of the variable and then uses different print statements depending on the size of it. Also as the year throws off alignment I've put some code that should fix that

```
if(month%12 == 0)
{
    // Set the amount of decimals for all interest rates
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    df.format(annualInterest);

    // Get the length of annualInterest
    int n = math.floor(annualInterest);
    int length = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1);

    if (length = 3)
    {
        // Have 1 less space than normal on the print statement
        // Maybe also do a check on the year also as that throws it out when it goes past 10
        if (year > 10)
            System.out.printf("%d     %.2f    %.2f \n",year,annualInterest,annualBalance);
        else
            System.out.printf("%d      %.2f    %.2f \n",year,annualInterest,annualBalance);

    }
    if (length = 2)
    {
        // Have 2 less spaces than normal
    }

    annualBalance = 0;
    annualInterest = 0;
   }
```